# Distance-based spatial weights in pysal

Tags: pysal

I run into errors with distance-based spatial weights in pysal. When running a spatial lag model (e.g. twosls_sp.GM_Lag), I get the following exception:

```
Exception: All entries on diagonal must equal 0.
```

Trying the example [here](http://www.pysal.org/library/weights/Distance.html), the diagonal is 1 (i.e., an observation is also its own neighbor), and the output is different from that given in the docs:

```
import pysal
points=[(10, 10), (20, 10), (40, 10), (15, 20), (30, 20), (30, 30)]
w = pysal.DistanceBand(points,threshold=11.2,binary=False)
w.weights[0]
    [0.10000000000000001, inf, 0.089442719099991588]
w.neighbors[0]
    [1, 0, 3]
```

After row standardization, there are only zeros and nans in the weights matrix:

```
 w.transform = 'r'
 w.weights[0]
     [0.0, nan, 0.0]
```

Is this a bug in pysal, or likely a problem with my installation?

I am running the Enthought Canopy Python installation, with pysal installed separately, on a Mac OSX 10.8. Pysal is v1.11.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/pysal/pysal/issues/726) that is currently being addressed.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I found is to use the [insert_diagonal](http://pysal.readthedocs.org/en/v1.11.0/library/weights/util.html) function. I'm still curious whether there is a problem with my pysal installation, however.

```
import pysal
import numpy as np
points=[(10, 10), (20, 10), (40, 10), (15, 20), (30, 20), (30, 30)]
w = pysal.DistanceBand(points,threshold=11.2,binary=False)
w.weights[0]
    [0.10000000000000001, inf, 0.089442719099991588]
w = pysal.weights.insert_diagonal(w, np.zeros(w.n))
w.weights[0]
    array([ 0.1       ,  0.08944272])
w.neighbors[0]
    [1, 3]
```

The new output is the same as the documented example, but I shouldn't need to manually modify the diagonal.